# Elementary crashes router when plug in Ethernet cable; Windows, no problem

Tags: dual-boot, ethernet, elementary-os, router

I've already tried this more than twice. I can connect my laptop via Ethernet cable to the router on Windows, but when I do so on Elementary, the router instantly crashes and reboots. I can use WiFi on both Windows and Elementary, problem-free.

I don't know if there is a driver issue.  My Wi-Fi card is Ralink RT3290 and my LAN card/device is Realtek PCIe GBE. I haven't found any good drivers for the LAN device.

Pinging the address used by Elementary for the Ethernet port 192.168.1.65 from Windows results in 'Destination host unreachable'.

After the request from the comments section here is the `ip a` command result run before plugging the Ethernet cable causing the router to crash not 5 seconds after:

`1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ec:b1:d7:94:a3:97 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 2001:8a0:f41a:c700:382c:d508:1bfd:e499/64 scope global temporary tentative dynamic 
       valid_lft 89999sec preferred_lft 85810sec
    inet6 2001:8a0:f41a:c700:1ad1:c9ac:3e23:852/64 scope global tentative dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 89999sec preferred_lft 89999sec
    inet6 fe80::a5e4:d:f5f0:25eb/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 38:b1:db:8e:e6:45 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.65/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlo1
       valid_lft 3437sec preferred_lft 3437sec
    inet6 2001:8a0:f41a:c700:c9d1:4675:a060:adef/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 89999sec preferred_lft 85739sec
    inet6 2001:8a0:f41a:c700:53f3:740b:2c3b:72dd/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 89999sec preferred_lft 89999sec
    inet6 fe80::9c64:fc55:a339:87e6/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever`

Comment: I just added it to the post. @K7AAY

Comment: Just did it. Got "Destination host unreachable."

Comment: Thank you for the testing, appreciate your patience. Anyone else have an idea?

Comment: To be honest, I came to your conclusion the last time I booted to elementary. I may be able to check my routers IP management tables.

Comment: People seem to have culled previous comments, so the comms are a bit patchy, but ... in the text section you're referring to 192.168.1.65 as the ethernet port's IP. In the output of `ip a` it shows up as the wifi IP address.  Are you trying to use the same IP for two interfaces? Could that be confusing your router?

Comment: On both Windows XP and Elementary OS 5.1 Hera after plugging Ethernet cable to a network card `Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8100/8101L/8139 PCI Fast Ethernet Adapter` I've gotten artifacts on the screen and unresponsive state of a system. Changing PCI slot for the card solved the issue.